# DLL Project using C++ Not Running in Visual Studio

Tags: dll

Working with DLLs using C++, I've come across an issue, the code builds but does not compile/run in Visual Studio. When I use Visual Studio 2017, the problem is "xxx.dll is not a valid win32 application", when using Visual Studio 2010, it's something like "xxx.dll is missing ", the code builds fine, it just doesn't run in Visual Studio, I'm a newbie in DLLs and need to use some sort of debugger.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs don't run. They contain code that is loaded by something else. You can't just run a DLL in Visual Studio. You need an executable (EXE) which loads the DLL.

You can set an executable which runs when you press Start Debugging. This is done in the properties of the project. By default, this is set to the variable `$(TargetPath)`, but you can change this to launch anything under the debugger.

I don't have VS2017, but here is the project properties for VS2015: [image: Project Debug Command]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was wondering what's the safe way to set up a .exe file? I go to:  Properties --> Configuration Properties --> Debugging --> Common, and there is a space to be filled out with the path to .exe file, or  $(TargetPath). Should I put the .exe file in the same folder with the .dll file? What's a good path for it?